# Handle classes with Matlab parfor loops

Tags: matlab, handle, parfor

I consult "Handle Classes" section of

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/objects-and-handles-in-parfor-loops.html

and write this:

```
parfor j = 1:length(stores)
    store = stores(j);
    dataj = somefunction(store.someproperty, data(data.store == store.id, :));
    stores(j) = store.dosomething(dataj);
end
```

where `dosomething` modifies `store`'s state. (`store` is a handle class).

The loop works fine with `for`; switch to `parfor`, and `store` object's state fails to be updated.

Is this a problem with Matlab's doc, or with my understanding of it?

UPD. Editing comments is a pain, so I continue here. Here's a toy class, with two methods, modifying the object's state.

```
classdef shop < handle  
    properties  
        stock = 10
    end    
    methods
        function clearstock(obj)
           obj.stock = 0;
        end
        function[obj] = clearstock2(obj)
           obj.stock = 0;
        end
    end    
  end
```

Now the test script:

```
n = 1;
shops = repmat(shop, n, 1);
sprintf('Stock before: %d', shops(1).stock)
% A
parfor i = 1:n
    shops(i).clearstock;
end 
sprintf('Stock after: %d', shops(1).stock)
% B
shops = repmat(shop, n, 1);
parfor i = 1:n
    shops(i).clearstock2;
end 
sprintf('Stock after: %d', shops(1).stock)
% C
shops = repmat(shop, n, 1);
parfor i = 1:n
    shop = shops(i);
    shop.clearstock;
    shops(i) = shop;
end 
sprintf('Stock after: %d', shops(1).stock)
% D
shops = repmat(shop, n, 1);
parfor i = 1:n
    shop = shops(i);
    shop = shop.clearstock2;
    shops(i) = shop;
end 
sprintf('Stock after: %d', shops(1).stock)
```

(A,B) leave the state unchanged, (C,D) work as intended/advertised. Now, my 'real', 'non-toy' objects' state is a mix of built-in and custom classes. (The state element that is not being updated is a cell array of numeric arrays). Are the latter to blame, I wonder?

UPD2. A user-defined handle class as a property - still working as expected.

```
%MANAGER.M
classdef manager < handle
    properties
        name
        salary = 100000;
    end
    methods
        function[obj] = manager(name)
            obj.name = name;
        end
        function giveraise(obj)
            obj.salary = 200000;
        end
        function[obj] = giveraise2(obj)
            obj.salary = 300000;
        end
    end
end
%SHOP.M
classdef shop < handle
    properties
        stock = 10;
        manager = manager('John Doe');
    end    
    methods
        function clearstock(obj)
            obj.stock = 0;
        end
        function[obj] = clearstock2(obj)
            obj.stock = 0;
        end
    end
end
clc
n = 1;
shops = repmat(shop, n, 1);
sprintf('Stock before: %d', shops(1).stock)
sprintf('Salary before: %d', shops(1).manager.salary)
% A2
parfor i = 1:n
    shops(i).clearstock;
    shops(i).manager.giveraise;
end 
sprintf('Stock after: %d', shops(1).stock)
sprintf('Salary after: %d', shops(1).manager.salary)
% B2
shops = repmat(shop, n, 1);
parfor i = 1:n
    shop = shops(i);
    shop.clearstock;
    shop.manager.giveraise;
    shops(i) = shop;
end 
sprintf('Stock after: %d', shops(1).stock)
sprintf('Salary after: %d', shops(1).manager.salary)
% C2
shops = repmat(shop, n, 1);
parfor i = 1:n
    shop = shops(i);
    shop.manager = shop.manager.giveraise2;
    shop = shop.clearstock2;
    shops(i) = shop;
end 
sprintf('Stock after: %d', shops(1).stock)
sprintf('Salary after: %d', shops(1).manager.salary)
```

Is it about value classes, then?

UPD3. No, a user-defined value class for `shop` property worked fine. I stop until I can come up with a reproducible example.

Comment: Where is the example E?

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo.

Comment: Okay, now everything is behaving as I would expect. I don't know why your actual code is not working.

Comment: Is this the answer? http://fluffynukeit.com/tag/loadobj/  Working to try it out...

Comment: Maybe, don't know your code.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky since we don't see the whole code, but my best guess is that `dosomething` method does **not** return the modified `store` object instance, and returns something else instead. When you run it with the usual `for` loop, this method actually changes `store` handle object. When you run it with `parfor`, however, the only thing that gets persisted outside the loop is the return value of `dosomething` that is assigned to `stores(j)`. Please try the following instead:

```
parfor j = 1:length(stores)
    store = stores(j);
    dataj = somefunction(store.someproperty, data(data.store == store.id, :));
    store.dosomething(dataj);
    stores(j) = store;
end
```

As an alternative, make sure `dosomething` returns the object itself, i.e.

```
function obj = dosomething(obj, dataj)
    % ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you. My code actually was following the second pattern, i.e. `dosomething`'s first line was `function[obj] = dosomething(obj, data)`,  but I had tried the first, more natural pattern before. (I am tempted to try something like `stores(j) = 42`, to demonstrate that `store` objects are not modified in any way inside the `parfor` loop). I hope to come back to this thread with a reproducible toy example, but the experience so far is not encouraging, and it looks like Matlab's `parfor` is not what it cracked up to be.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, and it lay outside of the presented code.

The `parfor` loop was inside a function, `simulateoneday`, which was called, in a loop, from function `simulatemultipledays`. `simulatemultipledays` would pass to `simulateoneday` an array of `store` objects, which would then go to `parfor`.

It wasn't `parfor` that was 'resetting' objects' state - instead, it was the `simulatemultipledays`-to-`simulateoneday` passage. When I 'absorbed' `simulateoneday` into `simulatemultipledays`, things started working.

I wondered if I had tripped up on pass-by-value-vs.-pass-by-reference, but hey, the code worked fine with `for` - it was `parfor` which broke things.